# Android Custom View (Table)

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-view

I have a problem figuring out how to create a custom android view that contains other views in it like a table. How can I create a method in that android custom view class for adding a view inside it, I would like to know how the parent view will resize and position the child view.

How can I create a table like view that I can use to add other views in ?

Should I extend **View**(since I actually want to create a view not a layout) or **ViewGroup**(since I want to add other views in it) ?

This is what I hope to obtain:

[image]

Comment: A [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) extends a View, so I would say ViewGroup.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks ! I saw that just now when reading the android ListView code.

Comment: Maybe I should start by learning more about android view and now rush in with questions. Where should I start ? I like books so a book about android views(GUI) whould be nice

Comment: I guess the first start would be to go through some of the android doc like [Custom View Doc](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). I don't know if there are good books.

Comment: I have read the android doc but I feel like it is not enough, a book would have been easier to learn from. Thanks anyway :)